# Laravel - Route [companies] not defined

Tags: laravel

I developed a web application with Laravel-5.8 as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Organization;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Organization\Company;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;

class CompaniesController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $companies = Company::paginate(25);

    return view('organization.companies.index', compact('companies'));
  }
}
```

The CompaniesController is in a folder called Organization while the companies view is in a folder called organization.

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/companies','CompaniesController@index');
```

navbar is as shown below:

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a href="{{ route('companies') }}l" class="nav-link">
     <i class="nav-icon far fa-image"></i>
     <p>
        Company Info.
     </p>
   </a>
</li>
```

When I clicked on the navigation sidebar, I suppose to see the companies index being displayed but I got this error:

> Route [companies] not defined

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to name your route to use the `route()` helper; `Route::get(...)->name("companies");`. There are plenty of results for your error if you do a quick Google search; you're not the first to encounter this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing an undefined named route. Try:

```
Route::get('/companies','CompaniesController@index')->name('companies');
```

This should solve your problem. You are having the error because you're referencing a named route which is not defined yet.

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes) for more information.

Comment: When I added 'Route::get('/companies','CompaniesController@index')->name('companies')''    the error changed to 'View [companies.index] not found'

Comment: Do you have a file `index.blade.php` in `resources/views/companies` folder?

Comment: Yes, I have an index page in resources/views/organization/companies

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`. What you should work though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to name your route?

```
Route::get('/companies','CompaniesController@index')->name('companies');
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to name your route:

```
Route::get('/companies','CompaniesController@index')->name('companies');
```